# Calculate the volume under a plot of kernel bivariate density estimation

Tags: r, estimation, entropy, kernel-density

I need to calculate a measure called mutual information. First of all, I need to calculate another measure, called entropy, for example, the joint entropy of x and y:

```
-∬p(x,y)·log p(x,y)dxdy
```

So, to calculate `p(x,y)`, I used the kernel density estimator (in this way, function `kde2d`, and it returned the `Z` values (probability of having x and y in that window).

Again, by now, I have a matrix of `Z` values `[1x100] x [1x100]`, that's equal my `p(x,y)`. But I have to integrate it, by discovering the volume under the surface (doble integral). But I didn't found a way to do that. The function `quad2d`, to compute the double quadrature didn't work, because I only integrated a numerical matrix `p(x,y)`, and it gives me a constant....

Anyone knows something to find that volume/calculate the double integral?

The image of the plot from `persp3d`:

[image: density estimate]

Thanks everybody !!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have the results from `kde2d`, it is **very straighforward** to compute a numerical integral. The example session below sketches how to do it.

As you know, numerical double integral is just a 2D summation. The `kde2d`, by default takes `range(x)` and `range(y)` as 2D domain. I see that you got a 100*100 matrix, so I think you have set `n = 100` in using `kde2d`. Now, `kde$x`, `kde$y` defines a 100 * 100 grid, with `den$z` giving density on each grid cell. It is easy to compute the size of each grid cell (they are all equal), then we do three steps:

1. find normalizing constants; although we know that in theory, density sums up (or integrates) to 1, but after computer discretization, it only approximates 1. So we first compute this normalizing constant for later rescaling;
2. the integrand for entropy is `z * log(z)`; since `z` is a 100 * 100 matrix, this is also a matrix. You simply sum them up, and multiply it by the cell size `cell_size`, then you get a non-normalized entropy;
3. rescale the non-normalized entropy for a normalized one.

---

```
## sample data: bivariate normal, with covariance/correlation 0
set.seed(123); x <- rnorm(1000, 0, 2)  ## marginal variance: 4
set.seed(456); y <- rnorm(1000, 0, 2)  ## marginal variance: 4

## load MASS
library(MASS)

## domain:
xlim <- range(x)
ylim <- range(y)
## 2D Kernel Density Estimation
den <- kde2d(x, y, n = 100, lims = c(xlim, ylim))
##persp(den$x,den$y,den$z)
z <- den$z  ## extract density

## den$x, den$y expands a 2D grid, with den$z being density on each grid cell
## numerical integration is straighforward, by aggregation over all cells
## the size of each grid cell (a rectangular cell) is:
cell_size <- (diff(xlim) / 100) * (diff(ylim) / 100)

## normalizing constant; ideally should be 1, but actually only close to 1 due to discretization
norm <- sum(z) * cell_size

## your integrand: z * log(z) * (-1):
integrand <- z * log(z) * (-1)

## get numerical integral by summation:
entropy <- sum(integrand) * cell_size

## self-normalization:
entropy <- entropy / norm
```

**Verification**

The above code gives entropy of `4.230938`. Now, [Wikipedia - Multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) gives entropy formula:

```
(k / 2) * (1 + log(2 * pi)) + (1 / 2) * log(det(Sigma))
```

For the above bivariate normal distribution, we have `k = 2`. We have `Sigma` (covariance matrix):

```
4  0
0  4
```

whose determinant is 16. Hence, the theoretical value is:

```
(1 + log(2 * pi)) + (1 / 2) * log(16) = 4.224171
```

Good match!

Comment: Would it be easier if I discretize _a priori_ and count the frequency at the bins width? Would it produce much more error estimation? Thanks.

Comment: I have been testing your method against the histogram, and something wrong may be happening. When I test your method on 1000 random samples (as you explain above), the entropy gives me values near zero. But, when comparing to theory, it isn't true, because it should give me log(n). I used some other entropy package, and it gives me the correct result ~ log(n). Do you know what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This is true for gaussian normal kernels, but what about for undefined densities? The test against normal density should produce good results, but, in my case, when testing against financial time series (not stochastic), these results had changed considerably, specially because of the bandwidth (the defaut is gaussian). I think I'm having some problems around the tails of the distribution. The problems abouts considering errors is that I have a extensive matrix to calculate in pairwise (time series), so I will consider more the visualization. Again, thanks for your help!