# finding probability of area in kernel density estimation using kde2d

Tags: r, entropy, kernel-density, estimation

I'm having a very hard time to calculate the probability of a point being in a particular area in a kernel density estimation. This will be used to show the probabilty of an animal moving around in a specific area.

Here is my sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(100,0,100)
y <- runif(100,0,100)

n <- 11
lims <- c(range(0,100), range(0,100))

f1 <- MASS::kde2d(x = x,y = y ,n = n, lims = lims)
```

Where f1$z holds the density estimations in a matrix. The corresponding plot is shown below:

```
library('plot.matrix')
plot(f1$z)
```

[image: density estimates]

Now, my goal is to find for example the probability of a point being in the cell surrounded in blue.

I wonder, if this can be achieved be simply calculating:

```
library(raster)
raster <- raster(f1)
df <- as.data.frame(raster,xy=T)
df$layer / sum(df$layer)
```

But I assume the solution must be to integrate somehow like described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356825/calculate-the-volume-under-a-plot-of-kernel-bivariate-density-estimation).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point surrounded in blue is the point `f1$z[3, 2]`. Multiply this value by the cell size as computed in the code you link to and have

```
xlim <- range(f1$x)
ylim <- range(f1$y)
cell_size <- (diff(xlim) / n) * (diff(ylim) / n)

f1$z[3, 2] * cell_size
#[1] 0.003765805
```

---

### Off-topic

To see that this will compute the probability over that cell, compute the density over all cells `f1$z`. It must be equal to 1.

```
norm <- sum(f1$z) * cell_size  # normalizing constant
sum(f1$z)*cell_size/norm
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! My problem is solved! =)

One more question: Considering all cells are from equal size, `f1$z / sum(f1$z)` should have the same result. Am I right?

Comment: @schlumpel No, they shouldn't. Unless it's a uniform distribution.